# Rails: gettext pot generation task generates empty files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, gettext

my problem is that in my app I want to generate the gettext .pot file with rake but I'm getting a file with no keys, only the header text ("Some descriptive title. Copyright (C)...").

I'm using the task gettext:find getttext_18n_rails. I tried before with the classic *updatepo* task but was the same. Perhaps am I missing any gem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I only know about the classic updatepo,

> GetText.update_pofiles("blog",

the blog part needs to match the name of the name used in the init_gettext "" in the controller, or you will get blank pot files.